# Как расположить две кнопки относительно кнопки по центру на одинаковое растояние

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть 3 кнопки кнопка 2 выровнена строго по центру, а две другие находятся на одинаковом расстоянии от нее. Как их таким образом расположить? Без использования сеток и фреймворков (bootstrap).

[image: Готовый вид]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: flex` + `justify-content: space-around` или `justify-content: space-between`

```css
.container-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-buttons">
  <button>button 1</button>
  <button>button 2</button>
  <button>button 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ты мой спаситель))

Answer (score 1):

Кросбраузерный вариант без использования Flex

```
.container-buttons button{display:inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1; vertical-align:top;}
.container-buttons{text-align:justify;}
.container-buttons:after{display:inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1;  width:100%; content:"";}

<div class="container-buttons">
  <button>button 1</button>
  <button>button 2</button>
  <button>button 3</button>
</div>
```